# Reject changes of a filtered store - Ext.NET/ExtJS 3.4

Tags: extjs, ext.net

First of all, different from what might seem I'm not trying to call

```
myStore.rejectChanges();
```

in a filtered store. That would be ideal, but upon code inspection and reading the documentation, I see that it won't work. I'll work with some example stores and explain what I wanna do in order to sort this out. Let´s say I have two stores:

```
<ext:Store ID="productStore" runat="server" UseIdConfirmation="true">
    <Reader>
        <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="productID">
            <Fields>
                <ext:RecordField Name="productID" Type="Int" />
                <ext:RecordField Name="productName" Type="String" />
            </Fields>
        </ext:JsonReader>
    </Reader>
</ext:Store>
```

The record fields are just bogus data to help get my point across. Next store:

```
<ext:Store ID="productHistoryStore" runat="server" UseIdConfirmation="true">
    <Reader>
        <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="productHistoryID">
            <Fields>
                <ext:RecordField Name="productID" Type="Int" />
                <ext:RecordField Name="status" Type="String" />
                <ext:RecordField Name="date" Type="Auto" />                          
            </Fields>
        </ext:JsonReader>
    </Reader>
</ext:Store>
```

productStore actually has a 1..1 relationship with productHistoryStore. It's not about products in my real scenario, but I thought it might be easier to use this example. I'll try to make it clearer:

```
productStore.data.items:       productStoreHistory.data.items:

productID: 1                   productID: 1
productName: 'product1'        status: 'available'
                               date: 04/01/2013
productID: 2
productName: 'product2'        productID: 1
                               status: 'unavailable'
productID: 3                   date: 06/01/2013
productName: 'product3'
                               productID: 2
                               status: 'available'
                               date: 04/01/2013

                               productID: 2
                               status: 'unavailable'
                               date: 06/01/2013

                               productID: 2
                               status: 'available'
                               date: 08/01/2013

                               productID: 3
                               status: 'available'
                               date: 04/01/2013
```

And finally, how the whole thing work: projectStore is bound to a GridPanel. Upon clickng a line, it opens a modal window containing only details regarding the clicked product:

```
<RowClick Handler="openHistoryWindow(rowIndex) />
```

And the handler's function:

```
var openHistoryWindow = function(rowIndex){
    var productID = productStore.getAt(rowIndex).data.productID);
    productHistoryStore.filter('productID', productID);
    historyWindow.show();
}
```

Actually, if there's a better way to find the value for productID RecordField of the clicked line, I'd like to know that too, as long as it won't mess up the whole structure presented here.

FINALLY, I can get to the point: historyWindow allows the user to change the selected product status. Specification requires that the window has a "Confirm" and a "Cancel" button. Like I said before, the actual scenario isn't about products, so it allows not only a user to change the status (more like add a new status; there's actually a bunch of other data there too), but it allows him to DELETE previously added statuses, and there's where sh*t hits the fan. Deleting a record from the GridPanel to which productHistoryStore is bound, using

```
productHistoryGrid.deleteSelected();
```

will remove it from productHistoryStore.data.items and insert into productHistoryStore.deleted on the fly. That's fine. If I raise a call to

```
productHistoryStore.rejectChanges();
```

upon cancellation, you'd think it would work. And it does, but it comes with a price. In a situation where, let's say, I deleted the last status for 'product 1' and confirmed it, then I deleted the status for 'product 2' and cancelled it, rejectChanges() will restore the deleted status for 'product 1' as well. That's the expected behavior from Ext but I wish to know if there's a way to cancel/reject only the changes of a entry that's actually cancelled not having to loop through the deleted array and removing them "by hand", which also would force me to re-add those entries to productHistoryStore.data.items by hand with a big pile of crappy code as byproduct.

By the way, commitChanges() upon confirmation IS NOT an option. Server-side perks.

Comment: Why is commitChanges() not an option? Do you want to update the changes server-side or not?